# Can one sort suggested methods based on return type?

Tags: swift, xcode6

Is it possible to adjust *Xcode* to display suggested methods according to their return type (of course it suggests only the methods that are appropriate)?
I provided a code snippet to further explain myself (see the comment).

```
 @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
     let title = sender.titleForState(.Normal)!
     let plainText = title + " button pressed"
     statusLabel. /* once dot is typed xcode suggest a bunch of methods alphabetically,
                     but I want them to be displayed based on return type, e.g. String
                     together, Int together et cetera..*/
    }
```

Comment: Not by default, but maybe this plugin offers this functionality? https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin